# @composi/gestures swipe with lit element

Tags: javascript, typescript, lit-element

I am trying to implement gestures with my `lit-element` using the library: https://github.com/composi/gestures

At the top of my file I have the following:

```
import { gestures } from '@composi/gestures'
gestures();
```

Then in my render function I have:

```
render() {
 return html`
  <div class="tablet-menu " id="tablet-menu-T">
  <div class="tablet-menu-body" on-swipe="${this._swipe}">
....
```

However the `_swipe` function is never called, so it doesn't seem that it registers the swipe command.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: do you need double quotes for on-swipe event?

Comment: Have you tried using the [`@event` syntax?](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/events#using-this-in-event-listeners)

Comment: call `on-swipe="${this._swipe}` as function., also replace on with @. `@swipe="${() => this._swipe()}`., in function `_swipe(){ console.log('triggered') }`

Answer (score 1):

This is using the wrong event handler syntax.

```html
  <div class="tablet-menu-body" on-swipe="${this._swipe}">
```

Instead of an `on-` prefix, use an `@` prefix:

```html
  <div class="tablet-menu-body" @swipe="${this._swipe}">
```

See: https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/template-reference#event-listeners

Note: you do not need to use arrow functions for LitElement class methods. They are called with the correct `this` reference automatically.

Answer (score 0):

**Make it arrow function**

```
<div class="tablet-menu-body" on-swipe="() => ${this._swipe}">
```

*Maybe syntax of my answer is wrong, but you have to apply it with arrow function*

Comment: You don't need to use arrow functions for methods on the host element. LitElement + lit-html take care to call the method with the correct `this` reference.